# Query para regresar record con valor distinto

Tags: sql

estoy tratando de crear una query para interrogar esta tabla:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Column1        |     Column2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          B          |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          A          |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

La query en question tiene que regresarme todas las `letras` del la `column1` que contengan un numero con valor diverso:

en este caso tiene que `regresarme la  B`, `ya que esta tiene como valor 3`, `si B tuviera solo 2s` como numeros no tendria que regresar nada. La A no regresa ya que tiene solo 1S como numeros osea todos son iguales.

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora:

```
SELECT distinct (column1)
FROM (SELECT b.numero_contratto FROM table b) column1
WHERE column1.periodo_date = to_date('2019-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: A que te refieres con valor diverso? La `A` también te devolvería por ser diferente a 1?

Comment: Disculpa, tienes razon, e editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo, que en realidad deberías contar los valores distintos no en `b.numero_contratto` sino en la columna cuyo alias es `columna2`. Luego agrupamos por `numero_contratto` y filtramos aquellos cuya cantidad sea mayor a 1, con `HAVING COUNT(...) > 1`

```
  SELECT b.numero_contratto, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT <columna2>)
      FROM TIM_TRCELL_ANALITICO b
      WHERE periodo_date = to_date('2019-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT <columna2>) > 1
```

Comment: Gracias, me olvide totalmente de usar un HAVING.